# Link contrast is too low on meta

Tags: bug, design, user-interface

I've noticed this a few times recently. For example, I completely missed the "and others like it" links in [this question](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2071/1672). They're visible enough in good conditions, but if your screen isn't the brightest or you're in a bright room, they're really hard to see.

Could be fixed by perhaps making them brighter red? (They're #742929 here, but #bd4646 on main.) Or a different color altogether?

Hope it's not too presumptuous to mark this one as a bug, rather than a feature request - I think it's making meta a little bit harder to use.

Comment: I agree. My vision isn't great and sometimes I completely miss links.